# SQLite UNION right only if left is empty

Tags: sqlite

In SQLite there is no such function to *UNION* only if left expression results empty set.

Consider these as two base tables *test* and *test2*:

```
create table test(
  id integer not null primary key,
  val integer not null
);

insert into test values(1, 10);
insert into test values(2, 20);
insert into test values(3, 30);

create table test2(
  id integer not null primary key,
  val integer not null
);

insert into test2 values(1, 100);
insert into test2 values(2, 200);
insert into test2 values(3, 300);
```

I have this simple query:

```
select * from test
union
select * from test2;
```

I want this to always query the first select and the second if (and **only if**) the first gives empty result.

To illustrate:

```
select * from test
union
select * from test2;
```

This shall return all rows from *test*, and then quit: don't touch *test2* at all.

Another sample:

```
select * from test where val > 50
union
select * from test2;
```

First query gives empty results, move on and do the second select, shall result all rows from *test2*.

I want this to be as fast as possible => therefore I don't want to add a subquery for the second select.

Here is the [playground](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oxtn7hncSGJs8zHAqH4Wzo/2).

Answer (score 0):

> I don't want to add a subquery for the second select.

Well, the two queries are functionally independent in the query, and there is no way for the second query to tell that the first one came up empty, unless you use a subquery.

So, you would typically use a `not exists` condition in the second query, with a subquery that matches the first query.

So:

```
select * from test
union all
select * from test2 where not exists (select 1 from test)
```

Or if there is a `where` clause in the first query:

```
select * from test where val > 50
union all
select * from test2 where not exists (select 1 from test where val > 50)
```

Comment: "I don't want to add a subquery for the second select." - Querying the first takes too much time (even if the result is empty)!

Comment: How about CTE? If I bring the first into a CTE, I can refer to it multiple times without being queried multiple times?

Comment: The problem is with `select * from test2`. It takes too much time (17s) even if `where not exists` stops it.

Answer (score 0):

A SQL SELECT is [declarative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declarative_programming). It expresses *what* you want, not *how* to obtain it. It is up to the db engine to convert it to a [query plan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_plan). Some SQL dialects allow to hint the engine to do things a certain way, but not SQLite.

The only solution is to query the two part from an imperative language (python, java, C#, ...) that allows you to implements the *do something first and check result* then *do something else*